# SSRS report fit in PDF

Tags: pdf, reporting-services, report

What is the best way to make the SSRS reporr fit in to PDF page.

Comment: As in, you want all the data to be exported to a single page PDF?

Comment: also see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/362902/how-to-get-rid-of-blank-pages-in-pdf-exported-from-ssrs#376691)

Answer (score 9):

Next time please indicate what version of SSRS you are working with...

If you are careful to design your canvas to certain constraints your should be fine. Typically the PDF is going to emulate a 8.5" by 11" piece of paper - considering margins you should keep the width of your report to less than 7" but I think 6.5" is best.

You can do this by selecting the report itself, the menu in BIDS (VS) should now have a report item which you can select to reveal Report Properties. In the report properties you can select the orientation as well as standard paper sizes and margins. Based on your paper size and your left and right margins you should be able to calculate the maximum width for the body of your report. Back in the report designer select the report body and look at the properties. The object drop down list should specifically say BODY, in this you want to ensure the size of your body (width) is not greater than the Report width minus the margins.

Answer (score 1):

```
For PDF you have to change page settings while creating report check below steps for that :

if you have large data on page you should choose below option
->Right Click on report 
->Click on Page Setup option
->Change page orientation Portrait to Landscape
->Click on OK

if you don't have large data on page you should reduce size of your table on report design page and change below setting:

->Right Click on report 
->Click on Page Setup option
->Change page orientation Landscape to Portrait
->Click on OK

Now check PDF file.
```