# SSRS giving a blank page at the end of report

Tags: reporting-services, reportingservices-2005

I am getting a blank page, at the end of my report in **SSRS 2005**.

I have a header logo and footer date values, and I have set the both to **PrintOnLastPage = False**, but I am still getting a blank last page.

Any ideas how to eliminate it? Thanks!

Comment: Given that the accepted answer is nearly link-only to [How to get rid of blank pages in PDF exported from SSRS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/362902/how-to-get-rid-of-blank-pages-in-pdf-exported-from-ssrs), I'd say this is a duplicate.

Answer (score 21):

This solution applies for SSRS 2008 R2. I am not sure about earlier versions.
On Report Properties page, under category Other, set ConsumeContainerWhitespace to True.

Other suggestions still apply: Make sure your Paper Size can contain Report Width and Margins. Remove any white space you may have on your Report.

Good luck.

Answer (score 5):

Setting `ConsumeContainerWhitespace` works, but may cause a catastrophic increase in report generation time, especially for very large reports.

An alternative solution is as follows and involves keeping track for yourself which record is the last record in your dataset.

## SQL - Track Row Number vs. Total Rows

[image]

You may use a technique such as the above to track Current Row # vs. Total Rows, just make sure that your "Order By" mechanism matches that of your main select statement.

## Add an end-of-record page-break to all but the last record

- Add a vertically-tiny rectangle to the end of your report body
- Rectangle Properties -> PageBreak -> BreakLocation -> End

Now, we want this rectangle to be visible when we desire a page break, and we want it to be hidden when we do not want a page break.

Thus, in the Rectanble Properties (right click) -> Visibility -> Show or hide based on an expression -> Expression Edit

```
 =Fields!RowNumber.Value=Fields!TotalRows.Value
```

**This will cause a page break to occur at the end of each record, except for the last record**

Answer (score 4):

Shorten the width of the report, dragging the right vertical side to the left.

Comment: this is a proven solution.

Comment: This worked for me

Comment: Sometimes the simplest explanation is THE explanation.

Comment: More generally, I had to make the Size attribute of the Body match the PageSize attribute of my Report. For good measure I also matched the InteractiveSize attribtue of the Report as well.

Answer (score 1):

I had a report that kept printing a second page.
Someone else had added the tablix and set a "Page Break" END property to the tablix.
When I changed this to NONE it solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I had a report containing a subReport.  The subreport had a 'PageBreak' property with the 'BreakLocation' set to 'Start'.  Changing it back to 'None' removed the blank page I was getting.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to what MikeGee had answered and considering this is a very old thread, I thought I would add my 2 cents. 
To avoid blank pages, set each "BreakLocation" property of each tablix to "None". Sometimes it defaults to "End" and the number of blank pages depend on the number of tablix in your report. 
For example if you have 3 tablix in your report and if each tablix has a "BreakLocation" property set to "End", you will have 3 blank pages.

Answer (score 0):

set `ConsumeContainerWhitespace` to True if it is 2008 R2.

Answer (score 0):

I had an image on the last page and when it's size was set to 210mm, 297mm (A4) it produced a blank page at the end of the report. But when I changed the height size from 297mm to *296.9mm* the blank page disappeared. This was using VS2013.

Answer (score -2):

Check your margins as explained above

+

If you have a tablix that dynamically adds columns to your report, check that the "runtime width" of you tablix is within your margins. At runtime, it may be larger than the body-width you specify in the designer.
(Note: it's impossible to do this with the designer; try reducing the size of your columns to see if the blank page disappear).