# Repeat Column Headers in RDL Report, New Page Appearing

Tags: reporting-services, rdl

In a simple report in SSRS, I needed to repeat column headers of a tablix. I did what I had seen on http://blogs.msdn.com/b/robertbruckner/archive/2008/10/13/repeat-header-and-visible-fixed-header-table.aspx (and many other websites) and it works. But it adds a blank page to the end of report preview! If I disable column header repeating, the blank page disappears.

How can I solve this? I searched a lot.

Answer (score 2):

it could be an issue with margins of your report. see [SSRS giving a blank page at the end of report](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/723103/ssrs-giving-a-blank-page-at-the-end-of-report)

This is usually caused because some of your page items... text boxes, rectangles, lines, tables... fall outside of the margins.

Comment: All my margins are set to zero!