# ssrs 2008 r2 pdf blank pages

Tags: layout, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have report with dynamic-width list which when exported to pdf has every second page blank. I followed instructions given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/362902/how-to-get-rid-of-blank-pages-in-pdf-exported-from-ssrs), squeezed everything as hard as I could - and it worked. However I also have footer inside which I have horizontal line that should continue through whole page width. If I make it long I have every second page blank, if I make it short - it stays that short. Also suppose I need to have textbox at the far right corner of a page, which again would make blank pages in pdf to appear. Is there any solution to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the line, if it is simply to separate the footer from the body of the report, try selecting the entire footer row and set the BorderStyle-Top property to Solid instead of having a line.

For the text box, it has to be entirely within the page dimensions or you will get a second mostly blank page. Left margin + right margin + report width <= page width. On one of our printers this still isn't enough so we have to reduce the right margin by another 0.05cm more (so 0.45cm instead of 0.5cm which it should be) to stop getting blank pages every second page.

Answer (score 2):

One thing I have found useful to diagnose exactly why SSRS is generating blank pages, is to set the background of the report (or report elements) to a non-white color. Generate the report again, then you can usually see what is being spilt over into another page. You can usually figure out what SSRS is doing, and tweak your report accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

Set the report property `ConsumeContainerWhitespace` to `True`.  I believe the default is false, so if you didn't think to `ltrim(rtrim())` in your dataset, something I often forget to do, then the whitespace could be causing it.