# More pages when exporting to pdf than word?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have a ssrs report that when exported to word gives ~7 pages. When exported to pdf it suddenly gives ~18 pages, a lot of blank ones only including header and footer.

I have a few page breaks in the report so information belonging together starts on a new page as the customer wants it. This particular report should be used for word, so it looks fine. But there was complaints about it not working properly for pdf anyway.

The Body width is smaller than Page width, Left margin, Right margin which according to this link can be an issue: [How to get rid of blank pages in PDF exported from SSRS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/362902/how-to-get-rid-of-blank-pages-in-pdf-exported-from-ssrs/376691#376691)
The total height however is 140cm.

Suggestions / Help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue I had was the format became .005 cm wider than what the Standard A4 doc allowed me, 210x297mm.

Answer (score 1):

just try to set "ConsumeContainerWhiteSpace" property of Report to True, by default its False.

I had tried that in almost same issue as yours and it worked!!!!!!!!