# SSRS 2005 funny page break issue

Tags: reporting-services, report

I have an SSRS report with some data-driven sections.

In one of the sections, the code generates a table with six options. The first five appear on a page together, then there's a page break, and I would think the sixth option would appear at the top of the page, followed by the rest of the report.

Instead, I get a blank page, the sixth option at the bottom of the page, the rest of the report, and a blank page at the end.

I've checked the width and length of the report and the settings seem to be OK. Any ideas what's going on here?

Comment: With the info you've currently provided, I think any answer will be similar to the ones in [this (duplicate?) question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/362902/how-to-get-rid-of-blank-pages-in-pdf-exported-from-ssrs). Have a look there, or try to provide us with a way to reproduce this problem. Without more info it's a bit of a guessing game for us, I'm afraid.

Comment: @Jeroen - If you want to answer this with your link, I'll accept your answer. The answer in that question solved my problem.

Comment: That's cool, but no need: let's just both hit the "Close" link and leave your question here, if anyone uses search terms from your question they'll find the answer as well. Good to hear your problem's fixed.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if the page width + the margins are equal to or less than the print page width, A4 or A3, etc.

If not this will cause the displayed page to exceed the printed page width creating a blank page then the last row of your tablix.