# First page is blank when exporting ssrs 2005 to pdf

Tags: reportingservices-2005

I created a very simple report in SSRS 2005 but when I want to export the report to a PDF file the 1st page is always blank!!! The reaming pages are all fine. I have no idea what it causing this.Any help is most appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

**Test 1:**
Check the report margins and page width. If the body width + margins are greater than page width you will get extra white pages (or split data). Check out this post

[How to get rid of blank pages in PDF exported from SSRS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/362902/how-to-get-rid-of-blank-pages-in-pdf-exported-from-ssrs)

**Test 2:**
See if any object (like tablix) have "page break before" set.