# Report Viewer Export to PDF (ASP.NET)

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, reporting-services, reportviewer

I have report viewer in asp.net project with C#. 
I see the report good in Chrome, and in the toolbar I have option to export it to:
pdf /word / excel.
export to word and excel work good, but when I export it to PDF, it's seperate the report to 3 diffrent pages. (altough it's enter in 1 page)

How can I fix that? and export it to one PDF page . (like the word)
(I attach picture to show the diffrents:
http://oi61.tinypic.com/mvgayw.jpg
)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check the Report page orientation and your page and body margins to ensure they fit in the page size you are using.

Please refer to this previous answer for details:

[How to get rid of blank pages in PDF exported from SSRS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/362902/how-to-get-rid-of-blank-pages-in-pdf-exported-from-ssrs/376691#376691)