# SSRS Export to PDF Issue (No Report title)

Tags: reporting-services, sql-server-2008-r2

I am using SSRS 2008 R2 and I am getting the issue with exporting in PDF. The report title(Description of your report) is visible when i export into excel but not visible when I erxport into PDF.

Could anyone help me on this?

Comment: please include any error messages you are getting.

Comment: I am not getting any error. The report exports to PDF correctly. But the Description above the tabular report section, is not visible in PDF expprt but visible in excel export

Answer (score 0):

You are asking,

### Either

1. Getting PDF exported SSRS report name as expected

### Or

2. SSRS report when exported, report title/header is not visible

---

### The answers are,

1. There is no way to acheive this in standalone SSRS.
2. This is already discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/362902/how-to-get-rid-of-blank-pages-in-pdf-exported-from-ssrs) (Report Properties).