# SSRS pagination - wrong scales after deployed, internet explorer 11

Tags: visual-studio-2008, reporting-services, reportserver

This is a pretty weird issue i guess, the underlying data is correct however when deployed to the report server, scales seem off. In Visual studio everything seems fine.

Is this a web browser issue ? I know that IE11 does not support SSRS 2008 R2  but why would it try to generate some off scales on graphs ?

this is dev
[image]

this is after deployed
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Issue was caused by shared datasets which were cached. Deleted and recreated the cached datasets and issue was solved.

Answer (score -2):

This might help:

```
BW + BLM + BRM <= PW
```

Where:

BW = Body Width

PLM = Page Left Margin

PRM = Page Right Margin

PW = Page Width

[How to get rid of blank pages in PDF exported from SSRS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/362902/how-to-get-rid-of-blank-pages-in-pdf-exported-from-ssrs)

[Removing Unwanted White Pages and Spaces in SSRS Report Builder](http://mekalikot.blogspot.com/2014/07/removing-unwanted-white-pages-and.html)

EDIT:
TITLE of the topic: "SSRS Pagination...."

Comment: I know, that is why, I said "This might help". AS you can see, the OP already hinted that it might be an IE issue. the page width has something to do with page rendering of a browser (IE).