# How to remove Page Header White Space in SSRS report

Tags: pdf, reporting-services

I had designed a report in `SSRS` the data and the report is displaying fine My problem is that when I export the report to `PDF` it consumes a White Space on the Top as in the image below
[image: SSRS Report Exported as PDF]

I had used this link [How to get rid of blank pages in PDF exported from SSRS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/362902/how-to-get-rid-of-blank-pages-in-pdf-exported-from-ssrs) to remove white space below the report

kindly someone guide me how to remove the White Space in the top of the report

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1.Go to the Report Property in design Mode

2.Go to Page Section and find margin value

```
margin :2cm, 2cm, 2cm, 2cm
```

update it to

```
margin:0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5
```

or Refer this

[How to get rid of blank pages in PDF exported from SSRS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/362902/how-to-get-rid-of-blank-pages-in-pdf-exported-from-ssrs?lq=1)

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the same issue for me, but our is printing white space where the Header would normally be, but only on pages 2..x.  In other words, the first page it does print the Header properly, however, we don't want it printing OR taking up the white space on subsequent pages.  I've got the ConsumeContainerWhitespace on the properties of the report set to True.

Comment: try to add some textbox with white space and apply condition of visibility if page no is 1 then visible "false" else "true".