# SSRS whitespace between body and footer

Tags: reporting-services

I have a report that looks good in view report, but when I print the report there is an extra space between the body and the footer.

Any help would be appreciated.

Screen shot

[image]

Comment: share screenshot here!

Comment: I am not able to share sceenshot . Pls let me know how to share it .

Comment: Can you please check this post - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post

Comment: Hi , pls view the screen shot

Comment: @pedram , the preview in report viewer is coming fine .but when exporting to pdf , space is coming

Comment: A footer will appear at the bottom of the page no matter how much data is in the body.  If the body data truly only has the 4 data rows + header, then that's all the body will show.  The footer will show at the bottom of the page.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't use a footer if you don't want the white space. A footer will always appear at the bottom of a page and a header at the top. Move the content of your footer to the body of your report by either creating another tablix underneath or inserting a new row outside of all your current row groups. To get the page break select the last (bottom) row in your body, select 'tablix properties', then on the general tab select 'add page break after.'

Comment: @TIZechieThanks for your help . but I need this information is in footer on each page . There is few hidden rows inside the tablix ,let me know if they are creating space inside the tablix .any help would be appreciated

Comment: @Renu Have you tried reducing your page size in report properties? Assuming you want to print this to a 8.5in X 11in sheet, adjust your page size height so that header height + body height + footer height = 11in. For example if your header and footer are each 1in then adjust your page height to 9in. Also see - https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/0a6ab82f-adb0-462a-b649-867fa4915a92/extra-spacing-issue-between-the-body-and-page-footer-in-ssrs-2005?forum=sqlreportingservices[link]

Comment: By definition a footer will appear at the bottom of the page based on the page size you have defined in the report properties. If the content of the report doesn't take up the whole page there will be space between that and the footer. As @Tizechie said, if you want the "footer" to appear directly after the content regardless of the page size then it needs to be in the report body, not the footer.

Answer (score 0):

Okay seems issues due to those hidden rows.

Do one thing, copy all your tablix/textbox or whatever the controls you have used inside the body part and add one rectangle with the same size it was previously using for your tablix.

Now, paste your copy part inside the rectangle and check.

*It will definitely work.*

Let me know, if you need more help on this.

*Thanks.*

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. unfortunately it is not  working . Still space :(

Comment: Data is coming fine in report viewer but in pdf there is space between footer and body .

Comment: yeah I understand your issue, seems you should - have you tried `ConsumeContainerWhitespace=true` (by default it will be false) - let me know if it helps - Also I would suggest to check this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/362902/how-to-get-rid-of-blank-pages-in-pdf-exported-from-ssrs/376691#376691)

Comment: I already set this property to true.even I checked all margin and body width+left margin +right margin <= page width .

Comment: btw just thinking, if you are using footer then definitely it will show below the page, and if we talk about body it will show till data is - then it will leave blank spaces until footer data. so it might not be possible. it will only allowed to show on site page or on report preview.

Answer (score 0):

Just reduce the size of body pane, header pane and the footer pane. If there is space between these three panes, when you print especially in case of a PDF document, it will include that blank space as well while printing. To overcome this, just make sure that that all three are aligned with least minimum space. Take a look at the screen shot.