# SSRS Render to PDF repeating last page

Tags: pdf, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

USING VS2013 and SSRS2012
I have a small ssrs report(2 pages) that displays perfectly in the report viewer and report server but when i export it to PDF the second page is duplicated. I have not seen this behavior with other reports and even this report when there is only one page. Is there something I should be looking for in the SSRS report?
Thanks in advance,
Hank Anzis

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/362902/how-to-get-rid-of-blank-pages-in-pdf-exported-from-ssrs?rq=1 check your margins they are usually the culprit.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - I am well under the margins. I am not getting blank pages - the last page is duplicated when the report is 2 pages.

Comment: Is one of your report objects growing? This can cause your report to have a blank second page. Check objects near the bottom of the page, and add a black border to the potential culprit.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. My report does not have a blank second page. The second page is duplicated onto a new third page when converting to PDF or printing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by changing the page break options. There are two groups on the report. The inner group had a page break on each occurrence and a page break at the start of the group. I removed the page break at the start of the group and there is no duplicated page on the rendering and printing.